# Which is better to use for API calls, Dispatcher.IO or Dispatcher.Main?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am using an MVVM architecture pattern in my Android application. I wanted to have API calls from my `ViewModel` using `coroutinescope.lauch{}` Do I need to specify the Dispatcher as `Dispatcher.IO` as it will be executed in an IO thread or just use the Dispatcher provided by the `ViewModel`, which is `Dispatcher.Main`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an extension property on `ViewModel` class, called [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) which works on `Dispatcher.Main` context by default. You can use it to call your api functions if they are `suspend`, e.g.:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    apiFunction()
    // do other stuff
}

suspend fun apiFunction() { ... }
```

It is OK to call `suspend` functions on `Dispatchers.Main` context, they will suspend a coroutine but not block the `Main Thread`.

---

If your API functions are not `suspend` you can convert them to `suspend` functions by switching context to `Dispatchers.IO` using `withContext()` function. Or if API functions use callbacks you can consider using `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. Example of using `withContext`:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    apiSuspendFunction()
    // do other stuff
}

suspend fun apiSuspendFunction() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { 
    apiNonSuspendFunction()
}

fun apiNonSuspendFunction() { ... }
```

Comment: But does that run on UI thread? or is it right to do the API calls in the UI thread?

Comment: Are your api functions `suspend`? Please add an example of an api function to your question.

Comment: It is OK to call `suspend` functions on `Dispatchers.Main` context, they will suspend a coroutine but not block the Main Thread.

Comment: Yes my API functions are suspend functions?

Comment: Then use `viewModelScope.launch { } `.

Answer (score 0):

**For api call Dispatcher.IO is better**

for more info

https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-coroutines-in-android-summary-1ed3048f11c3

https://miro.medium.com/max/720/1*K-5ZG6rVR5Dl9J5E3Rx7eA.png

And in your case you use mvvm so more better to use  ViewModelScope

```
    viewModelScope.launch { 
        // operation
    }
```